# Build a jquery custom calender with events

Tags: jquery, calendar

i need some hints to build an calendar. Is there a good solution for a calender, that get the Data from an Xml-file and show the Events only in the Year view??

Some like that?
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img849/5237/p6jr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following Bootstrap Calender in some projects. The code is well structured and quite easy to comprehend and use:

[Bootstrap Calendar](http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/)